# How to deal with ' or (&#39;) in CKeditor

Tags: smarty, ckeditor

I am unable to use smarty in CKeditor because it's transforming the ' into & #39;
I couldn't find anything useful when click the configure CKEditor Button in display preferences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can turn off html encoding for CKeditor through UI (i.e >= 4.7)

Navigate to Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Display preferences

Scroll down until you see `Configure CkEditor` button. Click on it to view all the settings. Under Advance options add `entities` option as `False`(as shown in image) and save the form.

[image]

**Note: You will need to clear your browser cache to reflect the changes(and CiviCRM caches).**

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. Works as expected. If you check the source code when viewing the page, the " should now be literal instead of being converted to a HTML entity ```&quot;```