# How to use Smarty for change greetings for French?

Tags: smarty

I need to adapt Greetings in order to fit to French (which has a feminine and masculine for "Dear").
I read on the forum that I should use Smarty and read the short documentation ([CiviCRM documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#smarty)) but I haven't understood how to use it :(

Where should the following code come (once adapted of course)? In the email source or in the greetings settings?

```
{capture assign=first_name}{contact.first_name}{/capture}
Dear {$first_name|default:Friend},
{if $first_name}
  Hello, {$first_name}, how are you?
{/if}
```

My second question is where do I set something like:

```
WHEN contact_gender IS female THEN contact_greeting IS Chère
```

Do I have to create any custom fields?

Any help will be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Pradeep's help I found the way:

For my case, this is the code to use

```
{capture assign=gender}{contact.gender}{/capture}
{if $gender eq 'Homme'} Cher {contact.first_name}, 
{elseif $gender eq 'Femme'} Chère {contact.first_name}, 
{/if}
```

I just needed to insert it where needed in the source of the email. FuzionFields was of a good help to find the correct string for the field Gender. It was also important to write `{contact.first_name}` and not `{first_name}` like writen in the documentation.

To make Smarty work with CKeditor you'll also need to set this parameter using Pradeep's other answer: [How to deal with ' or (&#39;) in CKeditor](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/how-to-deal-with-or-39-in-ckeditor/22618#22618)

I'm very happy to have this small but nice enhancement for our feminine members.

Comment: Don't forget that it doesn't work within Mosaico as Mosaico and Smarty are not compatible. Using a Mosaico template you have to find another way to personalize greetings :-(

Answer (score 5):

Try below code

```
{capture assign=contact_gender}{contact.gender}{/capture}
{if $contact_gender eq 'Female'}
  Chère {$first_name|default:Friend},
{/if}
```

or

```
{capture assign=contact_gender}{contact.gender}{/capture}
{assign var='contact_greeting' value='Dear'}
{if $contact_gender eq 'Female'}
  {assign var='contact_greeting' value='Chère'}
{/if}

{$contact_greeting} {$first_name|default:Friend},
```

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep! I was trying something like : {capture assign=gender}{contact.gender}{/capture}
{if $gender eq 'Homme'}
    Cher {$first_name},
{elseif $gender eq 'Femme'}
    Chère {$first_name},
{/if}

Comment: Cool, I hope you got it working?

Comment: How do I use this code? Direct into the email template? I can't succeed to send email with this code in the body :(

Comment: Yes, you can use this code in email template, make sure you switch off the editor when adding such smarty logics.

Comment: Switch off editor? HOw do I do that? Sorry for my questions :(

Comment: By clicking on the 'Source' of editor. It should on top left corner of the editor.

Comment: hit "Source" in the WYSIWYG.