# How to change Greetings in CiviCRM?

Tags: contacts

This was already [a topic](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31689/how-to-use-smarty-for-change-greetings-for-french) and I was able to fix it using Smarty and the help of the community but Smarty doesn't work with Mosaico and Greetings are showing pretty poorly in CiviCRM (dear e.g cher doesn't fit the feminine).

Is there a way to set the Greetings because it's not just a French situation as German also has grammatical gender. Is this a PR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the post you linked you said you would use a code like this:

> {capture assign=gender}{contact.gender}{/capture}
> {if $gender eq 'Homme'} Cher {contact.first_name},
> {elseif $gender eq 'Femme'} Chère {contact.first_name},
> {/if}

Instead of putting it directly in the template you could also add this smarty logic to the email greeting (/civicrm/admin/options/email_greeting?reset=1). CiviCRM would then generate the correct greeting for each contact and it also works with Mosaico etc.. For many of our German customers we use this logic to cover some more exceptions:

> {if "{contact.communication_style}"=="familiär"}{if "{contact.individual_prefix}"=="Frau"}Liebe{ }{contact.first_name}{elseif "{contact.individual_prefix}"=="Herr"}Lieber{ }{contact.first_name}{else}Liebe(r) Unterstützer(in){/if}{else}{if "{contact.individual_prefix}"=="Frau"}Sehr geehrte Frau {contact.formal_title}{ }{contact.last_name}{elseif "{contact.individual_prefix}"=="Herr"}Sehr geehrter Herr{ }{contact.formal_title}{ }{contact.last_name}{else}Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren{/if}{/if}

There are two issues with this approach:

If you change the greeting logic it will not automatically update all contacts. You could use the scheduled job that does that: (/civicrm/admin/job?action=update&id=7&reset=1)

Also the maximum length for the smarty logic is limited so can't go too crazy. If you need more complex logic and/or more different greetings, please have a look a the extension "[More Greetings](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.moregreetings)" which we developed a while ago.

Comment: this is definitely a great answer @Fabian! Vielen Dank. I tried yesterday to change the greeting but I wasn't using the right syntax. Using your logic, it worked perfectly. This is the equivalent for French: {if "{contact.gender}"=="Femme"}Chère{ }{contact.first_name}{elseif "{contact.gender}"=="Homme"}Cher{ }{contact.first_name}{/if}

Comment: Does it still work?

Comment: If you mean the extension "More Greetings" then yes, it should still work.

Comment: I dont' use the 'More greetings' extension, I mean just using this smarty logic for contact.email_greeting. It was working fine until recently :-/

Comment: @GuillaumeSorel it's probably far too late for you now, but this process is now called `update_greeting` rather than `update`. You can run it from the Scheduled Jobs console, just make sure you set `force=1` otherwise nothing much will happen.

Comment: @Hugh thanks for the information

Comment: I would advise against using `update_greeting` with `force=1`: although it does update all contacts and their greeting display it also changes the email greeting to the default option.