# Issue with sending html email from civicrm with Smarty

Tags: smarty

I am testing some templates with smarty and I don't succeed to send them when the email is - apparently - encoded in html. 
I could send them as normal text message. I could also send html templates that I have. But I can't send messages using **both** HTML template **and** Smarty.

I am sending from within Civicrm and it runs endlessly, when other types of messages are immediately sent (and well received).

Is this due to a limitation, a bug or should I set some parameters somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because you have syntax error in your smarty code. Try not to use editor if you want to use smarty code or use [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/how-to-deal-with-or-39-in-ckeditor/22618#22618) configuration to use smarty using ck-editor

Comment: thanks so much Pradeep! This was the last parameter to set. I will add the link to your message inside my other message about how to set the smarty variables.