# Issue with CK editor <wbr> tag appearing in Token

Tags: tokens, smarty, ckeditor

In the CK editor, when I add a token and look at the source code, the wbr/> tags appear in the token breaking the token. I have a feeling this crept in after I enabled Smarty for email. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how it can be fixed?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question twice.  The subject line is clear, not "problem with ckeditor"; the question gives all the information needed to provide help; there's a screenshot.  Thank you and welcome menachem - I predict success for you on Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring your ck editor as provided [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/22618/155).

Thanks

Pradeep